# Bulk renaming of .pst extractions in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a hopefully simple situation, only if I knew how to code in powershell. I have extracted all of our mailboxes into .pst and they are currently extracted with the naming of the Active Directory CNAME (FQDN of the users) and I need to make them into their appropriate SMTP addresses. There are some files that have are broken up past 1Gb and they have a .1, .2, .3.

I only need the script to match the name from sheet one and replace with corresponding SMTP address of that same user.

I have exported the list of all current directories in csv and I have their corresponding SMTP addresses in csv as well. Is it that simple?

Comment: The Export was from the Exchange mailbox into the "USERAD_DISPLAY_NAME" and I need to change it to the "PrimarySmtpAddress"

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the CSV and an example of the folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

This script will do it assuming I understood the situation right.

```
Import-Csv file.csv | ? {
    test-path "$($_.USERAD_DISPLAY_NAME).pst"
} | % {
    $n = $_.USERAD_DISPLAY_NAME
    $e = $_.PrimarySmtpAddress
    ls "$n.*" | % {
        ren "$($_.name)" "$e$($_.extension)"
    }
}
```